# Android string comparison

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare two EditTexts when the user clicks a button. However the IF statement returns true even if the two strings are different.

```
    final EditText email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    final EditText emailconf= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmailConf);
    final EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword1);
    final EditText passconf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPasswordConf);

    final String emailInput = email.getText().toString();
    final String emailconfInput = emailconf.getText().toString();
    final String passinput = password.getText().toString();
    final String passconfinput = passconf.getText().toString();

    //When our register button is pressed
 btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(emailInput.equalsIgnoreCase(emailconfInput)){
                if(passinput.equalsIgnoreCase(passconfinput)){
                    new RegisterTask().execute();
                }
                else{
                    displayDialogue("Error", "Your password's do not match, please try again", "Re-input details");

                }

            }else{
                displayDialogue("Error", "Your email's do not match, please try again", "Re-input details");

            }


        }

    });
```

If the two are correct then it will run an Asynctask (RegisterTask)

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Print to the console if the 2 strings that you are comparing are really different.

Comment: What do you mean by different? If they're the same except for case, that's expected when using `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: For exmaple, if I write test@test.com in email but bob@bob.com in the confirm email it doesn't display an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String passinput = password.getText().toString();
final String passconfinput = passconf.getText().toString();
```

Move this part to the `onClick()` so that the text is pulled from the `EditText`s only then. In `onCreate()` they're both empty and two empty strings will match.

Comment: Thank you - it seems like such a simple solution now - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is giving true in every case? Apart from equals method try compareTo method it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you Sanitise both fields, because if the user puts an empty space at the beginning or end of the field, `equalsIgnoreCase` will return false.

Try methods like `trim()`, remove invalid chars, and then compare, it's up to what you want to check.

Answer (score -5):

```
if(emailInput == emailconfInput){
```

if yout change to that you shouldnt have a problem... oh and i wouldnt suggest ignoring case on password check.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong approach. You cannot compare `Strings` with `==` operator that compares references. You want to compare values and not references.

Comment: OMG, Object Oriented Paradigm where are you?

Comment: please read the following it explains the difference between == and .equals(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: i am sorry i had used it in my code and it worked thank you for pointing out my error